# How to use me primary key strategy in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Entity (This entity parsed from itunes.apple.com)

```
/**
 * App
 */
abstract class App extends ContainerAware implements AppInterface
{
  /**
   * Using traits
   */
  use AppImageTrait,
      AppLanguageTrait,
      AppCommonTrait,
      AppCategoriesTrait;

  /**
   * @var integer
   * 
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(name="apple_id", type="integer")
   */
  protected $apple_id;
```

This entity has method setAppleId and getAppleId

And i want save primary key (id) as apple id

How this work?

Comment: This should alredy works. What is the problem?

Comment: Id auto generated (Autoincriment strategy) ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the docs for the [@ORM\GeneratedValue](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-generatedvalue) annotation:

```
class App implements AppInterface
{
    use AppImageTrait, AppLanguageTrait, AppCommonTrait, AppCategoriesTrait;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\Column(name="apple_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $apple_id;

    /* @param int $appleId */
    public function setAppleId($appleId)
    {
        $this->apple_id = (int) $appleId;
    }

    /* @return int */
    public function getAppleId()
    {
        return $this->apple_id;
    }
}
```

This should prevent the ORM from using an auto-incremental ID, while leaving to you the task of setting the identifier.

As a side note: do not make your entities container aware.

Comment: Thank, but update application i have a PDO error: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "apps_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (apple_id)=(547409501) already exis

Comment: You probably had a broken schema before, so you had duplicates.

Comment: No, i was trying create a new application be set appleId. If i loaded this applciation from repository, all GOOD! Thank!